# Convert JsonObject to List<T>

Tags: c#, json

I have this json value that I want to convert to a List

```
[{
    "id_cuenta": 1,
    "nombre": "Mercedes Luj\u00e1n",
    "apellido": "Llano",
    "ci": 123,
    "telefono": 123456789,
    "dispositivo_id": "355790037549877",
    "password": "holaa",
    "created_at": "2016-07-02 11:36:57",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-09 09:56:53"
}]
```

This is my code so far:

```
private List<cuentaObtener> mCuenta;

btnLogIn.Click += async(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                string url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cuenta_ci/" + ci.Text + "";
                JsonValue json = await ObtenerCi(url);

private async Task<JsonValue> ObtenerCi(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));

//Code to convert JsonObject to List<T>


                    // Return the JSON document:
                    return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
```

This is my class where I want to store values:

```
public class cuentaObtener
    {
        public int id_cuenta { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
        public int ci { get; set; }
        public int telefono { get; set; }
        public string dispositivo_id { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }


    }
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `jsonDoc.Cast<cuentaObtener>()`... Or, you know, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<cuentaObtener>>(jsonString)`, where you read the `jsonString` using `HttpClient`, instead of the archaic `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I change HttpWebRequest to HttpClient and I have this error = "System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no   extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: use HttpClient was a wise advice! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download this [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) (Right Click Project > Manager Nuget Packages)

Then you can use :

```
string json = null;
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = stream.ReadToEnd();
}

List<cuentaObtener> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<cuentaObtener>>(json);
```

If you're using HttpClient:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
List<cuentaObtener> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<cuentaObtener>>(json);
```

Comment: var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            string json = null;

            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                json = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }


            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<cuentaObtener>>(json);

Comment: I change my code like this, but I have this error = "System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no   extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: @meluluji if you use HttpClient then use : `string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you for the quick response and patience! You made my day :D